# How do I replace Data.Generics with GHC.Generics?

Tags: haskell, ghc-generics

So I've used syb for a long time, and often have functions like

```
friendlyNames :: Data a => a -> a
friendlyNames = everywhere (mkT (\(Name x _) -> Name x NameS))
```

What is the equivalent of this using GHC.Generics, assuming Generic a?

Comment: I think the answer may be Data.Generics.Uniplate.Operations.

Comment: Where are the definitions of `Name` and `NameS`?

Comment: They are from Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax - i.e. template-haskell.

Answer (score 4):

This might be the wrong problem to solve with GHC.Generics, but here's now you'd do it!

```
{-# Language TypeOperators #-}
{-# Language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# Language DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# Language FlexibleContexts #-}
module Demo where

import GHC.Generics
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

data Record = Record { field0 :: Int, field1 :: Maybe Record, field2 :: Name } deriving Generic

instance FriendlyNames Record -- body omitted and derived with GHC.Generics
instance FriendlyNames a => FriendlyNames (Maybe a)
instance FriendlyNames Int where friendlyNames = id -- no-op

------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- | Class for types that can be made friendly
class FriendlyNames a where
  friendlyNames :: a -> a
  default friendlyNames :: (GFriendlyNames (Rep a), Generic a) => a -> a
  friendlyNames = to . gfriendlyNames . from

-- | Replaces the second component of a name with 'NameS'
instance FriendlyNames Name where
  friendlyNames (Name x _) = Name x NameS

------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- | Class for generic structures that can have names made friendly
class GFriendlyNames f where
  gfriendlyNames :: f p -> f p

-- | Case for metadata (type constructor, data constructor, field selector)
instance GFriendlyNames f => GFriendlyNames (M1 i c f) where
  gfriendlyNames (M1 x) = M1 (gfriendlyNames x)

-- | Case for product types
instance (GFriendlyNames f, GFriendlyNames g) => GFriendlyNames (f :*: g) where
  gfriendlyNames (x :*: y) = gfriendlyNames x :*: gfriendlyNames y

-- | Case for sum types
instance (GFriendlyNames f, GFriendlyNames g) => GFriendlyNames (f :+: g) where
  gfriendlyNames (L1 x) = L1 (gfriendlyNames x)
  gfriendlyNames (R1 y) = R1 (gfriendlyNames y)

-- | Case for datatypes without any data constructors (why not?)
instance GFriendlyNames V1 where
  gfriendlyNames v1 = v1 `seq` error "gfriendlyNames.V1"

-- | Case for datatypes without any fields
instance GFriendlyNames U1 where
  gfriendlyNames U1 = U1

-- | Case for data constructor fields
instance FriendlyNames a => GFriendlyNames (K1 i a) where
  gfriendlyNames (K1 x) = K1 (friendlyNames x)
```

The GHC.Generics approach is more suited to situations where this kind of complexity can be written once and hidden away in a library. While the SYB approach relies on runtime checks, observe the GHC core that is generated for a friendlyNames that makes Record values friendly

```
-- RHS size: {terms: 14, types: 18, coercions: 0}
recordFriendlyNames
recordFriendlyNames =
  \ w_s63w ->
    case w_s63w of _ { Record ww1_s63z ww2_s63A ww3_s63B ->
    case $recordFriendlyNames ww1_s63z ww2_s63A ww3_s63B
    of _ { (# ww5_s63H, ww6_s63I, ww7_s63J #) ->
    Record ww5_s63H ww6_s63I ww7_s63J
    }
    }

-- RHS size: {terms: 19, types: 19, coercions: 0}
$recordFriendlyNames
$recordFriendlyNames =
  \ ww_s63z ww1_s63A ww2_s63B ->
    (# ww_s63z,
       case ww1_s63A of _ {
         Nothing -> Nothing;
         Just g1_a601 -> Just (recordFriendlyNames g1_a601)
       },
       case ww2_s63B of _ { Name x_a3Z3 ds_d5Z5 -> Name x_a3Z3 NameS } #)
```

Comment: For `V1` with recent GHC, I'd go for `gfriendlyNames v = case v of {}`. I think that expresses the point more clearly.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do what syb does - an syb function will work on *any* instance of Data, finding embedded Name values and modifying them.  This GHC.Generics function does not work on just any instance of Generic, it only works on explicitly declared FriendlyNames instances.  How is this more powerful than a conventional typeclass?

Comment: To answer my own question, no explicit `FriendlyNames` instance is necessary because `friendlyNames` is a method of a class whose one instance applies to every type that is an instance of `Generic`.

Comment: @DavidFox what Generics gives you is the ability to derive implementations of instances. Notice how `instance FriendlyNames Record` and others required no explicit implementation of the class method.

Comment: Yes, but even better is when the only instance of `FriendlyNames` only has the constraint Generic, then you don't even have to derive an instance, the `friendlyNames` method can be applied to any `Generic` value.  I believe you can remove `instance FriendlyNames Name` from your example and it will still work.  See also my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally have a satisfying answer to this question.   The guts of it are taken from glguy's answer above, but I'll add some wrappers and explanation that helped me connect the dots.  I will also make it more generic so it corresponds more closely with the tools provide by `Data.Data`.

The `everywhere` function will apply a function to every occurence of some `Typeable` type `b` within the argument value, which is represented as type `a`.  The `Typeable` instance is used to determine when `a ~ b` during the recursion.  Note that because `everywhere` is a method of class `Everywhere` and a default instance is provided, it will accept any type that satisfies the class constraints

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Typeable (cast, Typeable)
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Ratio (Ratio)
import Data.Word (Word8)

class (Typeable b, Typeable a) => Everywhere b a where
  everywhere :: (b -> b) -> a -> a
```

Here is the basic instance of `Everywhere`, it can be applied to any type which satisfies its constraints, in particular `GEverywhere` which is defined below for any instance of `Generic`.  The `OVERLAPPABLE` lets us supply instances for additional types that are not instances of `Generic`.

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Typeable b, Typeable a, Generic a, GEverywhere b (Rep a))
  => Everywhere b a where
  everywhere f = to . geverywhere f . from
```

Now we write a class `GEverywhere` which includes the instances that cover the type representation.  Ultimately, the job of this code is to recurse on the values of the fields inside this value.

```
class GEverywhere b f where
  geverywhere :: (b -> b) -> f p -> f p
instance GEverywhere b f => GEverywhere b (M1 i c f) where
  geverywhere f (M1 x) = M1 (geverywhere f x)
instance (GEverywhere b f, GEverywhere b g) => GEverywhere b (f :*: g) where
  geverywhere f (x :*: y) = geverywhere f x :*: geverywhere f y
instance (GEverywhere b f, GEverywhere b g) => GEverywhere b (f :+: g) where
  geverywhere f (L1 x) = L1 (geverywhere f x)
  geverywhere f (R1 y) = R1 (geverywhere f y)
instance GEverywhere b V1 where geverywhere _ v1 =
  v1 `seq` error "geverywhere.V1"
instance GEverywhere b U1 where geverywhere _ U1 = U1
```

This final instance is where the subtype is encountered.  We check whether it is the type we are looking for using the `cast` function from `Data.Typeable`:

```
instance Everywhere b a => GEverywhere b (K1 i a) where
  geverywhere f (K1 x) =
    case cast x :: Maybe b of
      Nothing -> K1 (everywhere f x)
      Just x' -> case cast (f x') :: Maybe a of
                   -- This should never happen - we got here because a ~ b
                   Nothing -> K1 (everywhere f x)
                   Just x'' -> K1 x''
```

Finally, there may be primitive types that occur within the types we are interested in that have no Generic instances.

```
instance (Typeable b, Typeable a) => Everywhere b (Ratio a) where everywhere _ r = r
instance (Typeable b) => Everywhere b Char where everywhere _ r = r
instance (Typeable b) => Everywhere b Integer where everywhere _ r = r
instance (Typeable b) => Everywhere b Word8 where everywhere _ r = r
instance (Typeable b) => Everywhere b Int where everywhere _ r = r
```

That's it, now we can use everywhere to do generic modification:

```
λ> everywhere (succ :: Char -> Char) ("abc", 123)
("bcd",123)
λ> everywhere @Int succ ("abc", 123 :: Int)
("abc",124)
```